# Programming a "Not - Gate" situation into a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Brand new to coding of any form. Simply put: I have 2 batch files written. 1 loads one configuration into a program (MultiMonitor), the other loads a 2nd configuration. Id like a 3rd file to act as a "light switch" Or a "NOT-Gate." Effectively, if last time it was ran, it launched the bat controlling config 1, this time it should load config 2.

Currently I just launch the appropriate .bat; but id like to simplify this so I only have one file to launch and then it chooses the one not chosen last time.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

In option1.bat (in addition to the real work):

```
echo call option2 > autoselect.bat
```

In option2.bat

```
echo call option1 > autoselect.bat
```

Comment: The _space_ before `>` becomes echoed and therefore written to the file as well, so better write `> autoselect.bat echo call option#`...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this:

Use a permanent environmental variable using `setx` - NOT RECOMMENDED

Test which config is currently being used by your program - I am unfamiliar with your program so I do not know if this is even possible.

**Use a temporary file**

This example shows how to do this with a temp file:

```
if not exist file.ext (
    rem load config #1
    echo.>file.ext
) else (
    rem load config #2
    del file.ext
)
```

The file can be named whatever you want.